# Connection still exist after Destroy twilio.device

Tags: javascript, twilio, odoo-10

**Dial** button **setup** twilio device and create an active connection for make call and device will **destroy** on call **hang up**. 
I want to **destroy all active connections** when twilio **device destroys**.
Only one active connection at a time.

Code something like.

```
Dail : function(){
    Twilio.Device.setup(result);
        Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) {
            $("#log").text("Ready");

            Twilio.Device.connect();
            Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) {
                Twilio.Device.destroy();
            })
}

hang_up : function(){
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}
```

It shows me error when I'll create more than one call without refresh tab.

**errors:**
A connection is currently active. Error caught using device.error().

```
Twilio.Device.error(function(error) {
    console.log(error.message);  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Twilio Dev here,

`Device.setup()` should only need to be called once, and `Device.destroy()` should only be called during clean-up. Here's an example of how you might set up multiple outgoing calls:

```
var activeConnection = null;
Twilio.Device.setup(token);

// Connect handler
Twilio.Device.connect(function(conn) {
  activeConnection = conn;

  // Disconnect handler
  conn.disconnect(function() {
    activeConnection = null;
  });
});

// When user hits dial button
function dial() {
  if (activeConnection) {
    // If we're already in a call, do nothing.
    return;
  }

  Twilio.Device.connect();
}

// When user hits hang up button
function hangUp() {
  if (activeConnection) {
    activeConnection.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's something different. Call completely disconnected when I click hang_up button but when I make another call without refresh browser tab it'll trigger two active connections for single call and for third call 3 active connections.

Comment: Make sure you're not binding the `device.connect()` on response to the button being clicked. `device.connect()` should only be called once to set a handler, if it's set multiple times you will set multiple handlers. Notice in my example code above, the `Twilio.Device.connect()` handler is set once, not inside the `dial` function.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you call [`Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) { ... });`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#disconnect) that doesn't disconnect the call. Instead it sets up an event handler for when a call is disconnected.

What you need to do instead is to disconnect the call using [`Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/device#disconnect-all). You can also setup a handler for the `disconnect` event so that you destroy the device at that point. Your code might look a bit like this:

```
Dial : function(){
    Twilio.Device.setup(token);
    Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) {
        Twilio.Device.connect();
        Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) {
            Twilio.Device.destroy();
        })
    });
}
hang_up : function(){
    Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: still getting same error --> A connection is currently active
onaddstream is deprecated! Use peerConnection.ontrack instead.

Comment: Which version of Twilio Client are you using?

Comment: I'm using twilio 6.1.3

Comment: That will be the server side module you are using. Which Twilio Client, that is the front end JavaScript, version are you using?

Comment: It's inside code of call function..

Twilio.Device.setup(result);
   Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) {
    $("#log").text("Ready");
    Twilio.Device.connect();
    Twilio.Device.disconnect(function(conn) {
              Twilio.Device.destroy();
          })
   });

Comment: and called from ... 


on_click_dial : function() {
   this.call();
  },
  on_click_hangup : function() {
   
   Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
  },

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147715/discussion-between-vishal-khichadiya-and-philnash).